# Allow Non-administration Windows accounts auto update application

Tags: c#, admin

I'm making an Windows Form application using C# 4.0 and Ubuntu PC will a host for ClickOnce Deployment. The users' Windows accounts are not admin accounts. Is there any way for the users to update the application without typing admin password If there are updates?

EDIT : Or is there anyway, when the application is installed on the user's machine initially, i register my application on Windows system saying that any updates from this application can be done without admin privilege?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it depends if the application requires any Elevated privileges. If the updates do not involve any registry changes or any system level DLL changes, There should not be any problem in updating the application.

if it requires elevated privileges then An administrator can advertise an application on a user's computer by assigning or publishing the Windows Installer package using application deployment and Group Policy. This way when the non-administrator user can install the application.